# How do i add links to items to the array of items to be searched

Tags: javascript, arrays, autocomplete

how to i add links to each items in my suggested item array, once i make a search i neeed it to take me to the page where those items are contained. i already coded the autocomplete search using vannila javascript

here is the javascript code

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    var currentFocus;
    inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        var a, b, i, val = this.value;
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) { return false;}
        currentFocus = -1;
        a = document.createElement("p");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
            b = document.createElement("DIV");
            b.innerHTML ="<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
            b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length) ;
            b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
            b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                closeAllLists();
            });
            a.appendChild(b);
          }
        }
    });
    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
          currentFocus++;
          addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
          currentFocus--;
          addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (currentFocus > -1) {
            if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
          }
        }
    });
    function addActive(x) {
      if (!x) return false;
      removeActive(x);
      if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
      if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
      x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }
    function removeActive(x) {
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
      }
    }
    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
          x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
  }
  autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

what i did here is that, when the value is been entered, it will concatenate with this and take me to the needed page, but i can not do it that way, i am thinking there could be another way

```
  document.getElementById('searchform').onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.skyyonliquor.com' + "/" + document.getElementById('myInput').value +"-section.html";
    return false;
```

my suggestions array i need to add links to:

```
var countries = [ 
    "Spirit","Whiskey","Rum","Vodka","Brandy & Cognac","Malibu","Tequila","Chateau Mouton Rothschild","Chateau Margaux","Baron Philippe de Rothschild Mouton Cadet","Dom perignon","Moet Imperial","Moet Nectar Imperial Rose","Veuve Clicquot Rose Demi Sec","Clase Azul","Barware","Vodka","Gin","Champagne","Hennessy V.S.O.P","Hennesy X.O","Martell Blue Swift","Martell VSOP","Johnnie Walker Blue Label","Jack Daniels Old No. 7","Jack Daniels Honey","Jameson Black Barrel","Black Velvet","Kavalan"];
```

can i get any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your array and create an `A` HTML element with the address you want, and append it to the element you want it to be displayed in.

```js
var countries = [ 
    "Spirit","Whiskey","Rum","Vodka","Brandy & Cognac","Malibu","Tequila","Chateau Mouton Rothschild","Chateau Margaux","Baron Philippe de Rothschild Mouton Cadet","Dom perignon","Moet Imperial","Moet Nectar Imperial Rose","Veuve Clicquot Rose Demi Sec","Clase Azul","Barware","Vodka","Gin","Champagne","Hennessy V.S.O.P","Hennesy X.O","Martell Blue Swift","Martell VSOP","Johnnie Walker Blue Label","Jack Daniels Old No. 7","Jack Daniels Honey","Jameson Black Barrel","Black Velvet","Kavalan"];

const parent = document.getElementById("myElement");

for(let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
{
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.textContent = countries[i]; //displayed text
  a.href = "http://example.com/mysearch?q=" + countries[i] + "&myquery=blah"; //link
  //a.className = "myLink"; //style if needed
  parent.appendChild(a);
}
```

```css
#myElement > a.myLink
{
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your response. but the items have different links, how do i go about that?

Comment: Sorry, not following the question...if they are different links, you update the code to accommodate them...

Comment: if i knew how to do that, i would not beasking the question :), can you please help to demonstrate the code out.

for example: 
SPIRIT is part of the array item.

and when SPIPIT is been searched, it sholud go to this link:
https://skyyonliquor.netlify.app/whisky-section.html